# Facebook AnE Android: Login Activity - .ApiException: code 1: an unknown error has occurred

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login, adobe-native-extensions

After logging in to connect my app to the player's facebook, all I get is a facebook overlay with 'Error' as its title and 'Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this request.' in the body.

This happens after hitting the sign in button with my login and password. Perhaps when I try to connect the facebook account to my app? I do know I get the following output just after logging in. In logcat it's before the error and its call stack:

I/ActivityManager(  505): Displayed air.com.mycompanyname.MyAppName.debug/com.facebook.LoginActivity: +186ms (total +711ms)

I'm totally lost and can't find anything on this specific type of ApiException. Thanks for any help in advance.

Error and Call Stack:

```
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442): Exception during service
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: [code] 1 [message]: An unknown error occurred [extra]: null
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:84)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:163)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.h(ApiResponse.java:188)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:275)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:31)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:55)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:28)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:570)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:203)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.d(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:157)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:308)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:510)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:242)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:20)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.platform.common.server.SimplePlatformOperation.a(SimplePlatformOperation.java:40)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.platform.common.server.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:60)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:360)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:58)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:280)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:58)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(18442):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Have you got any solution?

Comment: This was due to the Facebook User not being a tester on a test app. I believe so anyway. It was a while ago so I don't remember fully. Check that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that the user was not added as a tester to the test app we had created.